# Intuit Partner Platform Quickbooks API in .Net 3.5?

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, .net-3.5, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I am trying to work with the IPP Quickbooks and have a working proof of concept working. My problem however is that it is in .Net 4.0 and the project I need to integrate it into is .Net 3.5. I was wondering if there was a place where I'd be able to access previous versions of the API?

Answer (score 0):

The API version does not change with the .net version you are using.
We have a V2 version of the Quickbooks APIs and now we have released V3 version for some early developers.

Just wondering why don't you upgrade your POC to 4.0? It would work much easily that way with integrations.

For sample application for quickbooks, you can download the code from here:
You can download sample app from the GITHUB-

https://github.com/IntuitDeveloperRelations/IPP_Sample_Code